# How to look up your contacts and see who can I talk with iMessage?

Tags: contacts, ios, messages

How can we quick look at our contacts and see how is having [iMessage](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html#imessage) or not? So we can easily contact them, instead of going through all contacts one by one to check them.

Comment: I don't think you can. I think iMessage is supposed to be seamless with SMS. If the contact doesn't support iMessage, it'll fall back to standard SMS. It's not meant to be a "standout service," if that makes sense. Maybe they had to appease the carriers and push it deep into the background, maybe they wanted to do this all along. In any case, it would be nice, but at this point, I don't think you can differentiate users with iOS 5 and those without (other that the current method you are using).

Comment: @chksum If you make that the answer, I would up vote since your 100% correct. The only way to confirm iMessage is by sending a message, if the Apple servers are available, and the other person has iMessage, it will send, otherwise it falls back on SMS.

Answer (score 3):

The feature you are looking for does not exist in iOS 5.0. I guess the reasoning is that you just want to send a message to your contacts and the device will send it via the appropriate route, favouring iMessage where it is available.

The closest you can get to seeing who has iMessage available **without visiting each contact's card individually** is if you go to send a new message, type 'a' in the `To:` field and you'll get a phone-number drop down. As you scroll, those contacts with iMessage available will have a little blue speech bubble to the right of their name and number (or email address).

[image: Blue speech bubble]

Other that that, when you're sending a message...

If the Contact's Name and the Send button are green, then they don't have iMessage available and you'll send them an SMS (or MMS).

[image: iMessage unavailable]

If the Contact's Name and the Send button are blue, then they do have iMessage available and you'll use that.

[image: iMessage available]

Comment: not quite, your first assumption is not correct, [see this link](http://balexandre.com/temp/2011-10-15_1303.png) hat contact has **iMessage** enable and I get nothing different from all the others. The second part is the obviously one and I stated on my answer, it's not that I'm trying to find...

Comment: You don't actually have to *send* the message, just go to send it. The button is coloured blue fairly quickly after you select the contact.

Comment: well, if that's your answer, it's just wrong as I specifically mention that I do not want to go through each contact!

Comment: Sorry I cannot give you the answer you are looking for. I've updated my answer so that it may help others who stumble across this page.

Comment: I'm sure that's because you already used **Gary** before, but the original question is, if I can see anyone at once. *P.S.* you can always use a small size when uploading images from your mobile device, [Cloudette](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloudette-for-cloudapp/id393113270?mt=8) is a lovely client for [CloudApp Service](http://getcloudapp.com/)

Comment: I've not *actually sent* a message to that Gary using iMessage. Thanks for the tip on posting pictures.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1597/discussion-between-johnsyweb-and-balexandre)

Comment: +1, this was just what I needed to know. (The blue speech bubble & blue vs green colour in "new message" screen.)

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for a month but didn't find any method any trick not any 3rd party app or not even a Cydia tweak to identify all my iMessage users & the point of hitting compose new and add a user to check if it turns green or blue.

In short there's no way you can find it so don't waste your precious time for searching.

Comment: You surely saved your precious time by not typing all those unnecessary letters.